# With GetJSON, I lose the properties

Tags: geojson, getjson

With this file "segment.geojson", I draw a red segment of thickness 20 :

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "stroke": "#ff0000",
                "stroke-width": 20,
                "stroke-opacity": 1
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [[-3,48],[7,45]]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and with getJSON I display it on my map:

```
    
<body>
    <div id="viewerDiv"></div>
    <script>
        window.onload= function() {
            var map = L.map("viewerDiv").setView([50,50],5) ;
            L.tileLayer(...blabla...).addTo(map);
            var segment = '';
            $.getJSON("segment.geojson", {dataType: "json"}, function (data) {
                segment = new L.GeoJSON(data);
                map.fitBounds(segment.getBounds());
            })
            .done(function () {
                segment.addTo(map);
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

but it is blue and thick 1 !!! Can anyone help me? thank you in advance, JLC

The source is here: https://cavaliers23.fr/iti/ign/test_couleur.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong definition. You should pass the style as a second argument.

```
$.getJSON("segment.geojson", { dataType: "json" }, function (data) {
      segment = new L.GeoJSON(data, {
        style: {
          color: "#ff0000",
          weight: 20,
          opacity: 0.65,
        },
      });
```

You can also pass individual styles to features using the properties field

```
"features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "color": "blue"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [-3, 48],
          [7, 45]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "color": "red"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [-33, 48],
          [7, 45]
        ]
      }
    }
$.getJSON("segment.geojson", { dataType: "json" }, function (data) {
      segment = new L.GeoJSON(data, {
        style: (f) => {
          switch (f.properties.color) {
            case "red":
              return {
                color: "#ff0000",
                weight: 20,
                opacity: 0.65,
              };
            case "blue":
              return {
                color: "#0000ff",
                weight: 20,
                opacity: 0.65,
              };
          }
        },
      });
```

Comment: Thank you very much ... and it works!
But this method will be a bit complicated to install if there are several "segments" with several colors in the "segment.geojson" file! Is this also your opinion?
Sincerely, JLC

Comment: You can add individual style to features using the property field. I've updated the answer with how you can do it.

Comment: Hello, thank you, your solution is working very well:
 - with the file  [link](https://cavaliers23.fr/iti/ign/xuan.geojson)  
 - and with the program  [link](https://cavaliers23.fr/iti/ign/test_couleur_3.html)
Just a detail, your file « xuan.geojson » is valid with  [link] (https://jsonlint.com/) but is not valid with  [link](https://geojson.io). But it does not matter.
Sincerely, JLC